# Nest JS - cluster

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have this code for Nest JS that should make more workers to the application, on express js with TS goes perect but on Nest I have this problem. An idea of how it can be solved? Error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21L2.png)

```js
import cluster from "cluster";
import * as os from 'os';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

@Injectable()
export class AppClusterService {
    static clusterize(callback: Function): void {
        if(cluster.isMaster){
            console.log(`Master server started on ${process.pid}`);
            for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
                cluster.fork();
            }
            cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
                console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died. Restarting`);
                cluster.fork();
            })
        } else {
            console.log(`Cluster server started on ${process.pid}`)
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `import * as cluster from 'cluster'`?

Comment: I tried and I got some error like Property 'fork' does not exist on type 'typeof import("cluster")'.

Answer (score 3):

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
```

instead of `import cluster from "cluster";` works for me.